# How to make my app open png files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cfdocument

When a user search for images in net and he/she is selecting it, i want my app to be registered to open it. This is what I have included but the app is not detecting image files!

```
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>PNG Image</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
<array>
    <string>png</string>
    <string>PNG</string>
</array>
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Alternate</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>public.png</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is only available for Mac OS X, not for iPhone. It is explained here: [DocumentBasedApplications -- editor and viewer role](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CFBundleTypeRole)

On iOS your application is in a sandbox ([The Application Runtime Environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3)).

> Each application has access to the contents of its own sandbox but
>   cannot access other applications’ sandboxes.

Comment: But I was able to access pdf document with my app by including it in the plist. It ran on ipad. any idea??

Comment: files that you include in your app's bundle are in your app's sandbox and can be accessed (such as your pdf).

Comment: Nope! What I meant was my app was able to open a pdf from an email attachment. It was not there in the sandbox. If this possible why not png file?